# Parameter Not Found Error in my Jenkins pipeline

Tags: parameters, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, aws-ssm

I have a Jenkins pipeline which is associated with an AWS Service which has Parameters of a key attached. Whenever I try to extract the key details through back-end, I can view the parameter details, but when I try to do the same through a pipeline code using groovy syntax  to display and access this parameter, I'm getting this error

**+ aws ssm get-parameter --name privatekey

- grep -oP (?<="Value": ")[^"]***
  An error occurred (ParameterNotFound) when calling the GetParameter operation:**

The command I used to extract the parameter value is
**aws ssm get-parameter --name privatekey | grep -oP (?<="Value": ")[^"]***

Can you suggest me a way to access and get my parameter values through pipeline code thereby showing my o/p in the pipeline job...

Comment: Couldn't post the picture due to lack of reputation..

Comment: Found the solution, Include the location as parameters and keys are location-dependent
Modify the above command to the one below. I used a shell block .
string privkey = sh (
            returnStdout: true,
            script:  """
            aws ssm get-parameter --name "privatekey" --region ${region} | grep -oP '(?<="Value": ")[^"]*' > ECSPrivateKey  """  
        
        ).trim()
        echo " privkey: $privkey"

Comment: Post your comment as solution?